# How much could a real world quetzalcoatlus carry?

Tags: biology, worldbuilding-process

This question has been asked in dnd5e, and that is all google is pulling up for me is dnd related. Is there a study or a simple explanation anyone has I can look at? I'm looking to see if it would be possible for ancient civilizations to have used them like war elephants, or have natives ride them as part of a ritual. If they can bear humans, how much weight? Would they have use still in the 1800s?

Comment: I don't see the "building" part of your worldbuilding question. What makes it more than a pure biology/paleontology question ?

Comment: @Tortliena Quetzalcoatus have been used before with riders, so I want to know what the limits are, so if I can have them carry a lot, like a pilot and several bombs, then use them for a secret infiltration mission.

Comment: Why is carry capacity important? Does it determine what size prey they cut in half before carrying the meat away?

Comment: @SageGrant [Please add this worldbuilding context](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/249530/edit). There's a huge difference between theorizing a creature's strength and flight ability vs building a world where you have people flying on dinosaurs. The latter has actual worldbuilding constraints (it's not just maximizing weight anymore), it also has muuuucchh more freedom in its answers. Why? Artistic expression and [actual](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10202/80336) necessity.

Comment: What's with the "real world" in the question? _Quetzalcoatlus_ **are** real world, they're just extinct.

Comment: @JackAidley as OP explains, all they're getting are results for the DnD Queztalcoatlus, which is a fictionalized version. OP wants the real stats for the real creature, hence "real Queztalcoatlus"

Comment: Is anyone in this Q/A considering the very different air pressure when Queztalcoatlus was alive. Wouldn't that favor flight for bigger animals? Isn't that why birds today are smaller?

Comment: @combinatorist my thought was very similar. Oxygen content in the air during the late cretaceous (when quetzalcoatlus) lived was approximately 50% higher than today, which helped support larger animals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two [*Quetzalcoatlus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatlus) species, a large one named *Q. lawsoni* and a very large one named *Q. northropi*.

- *Q. lawsoni* had a wingspan of 4.5 to 5 meters (15 or 16 feet), and a body mass anywhere between 20 and 65 kg (44 to 143 pounds), depending on who made the estimation. (The thing is that [azdarchids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azhdarchidae) were so completely unlike any living animal that paleontologists have to do a lot of imaginative guessing when trying to come up with a body mass estimation.)

  A modern [harpy eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpy_eagle), *Harpia harpyja*, with a mass about half of the lower estimate for *Q. lawsoni*, and a wingspan also about half, can lift up to 18 kg (40 pounds).
- *Q. northropi* was much larger, with a wingspan of about 10 meters (33 feet) and a body mass anywhere between 70 and 200 kg (154 to 440 pounds), again depending on who made the estimation.

  There is no modern flying bird even remotely comparable in terms of body mass and wingspan.

  There is still some debate on whether *Q. northropi* flew or didn't fly, and, if it *did* fly, whether it was capable of powered flight or only of gliding, and, if it *was* capable of powered flight, whether it could sustain powered flight or used it only in short bursts.

  For comparison, a common-or-garden modern unpowered [sailplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(sailplane)) with a dry mass of 200 kg and a wingspan of 15 meters is perfectly capable of carrying a pilot and some ballast, and a moderately skilled pilot can fly reasonably long distances (hundreds of kilometers or miles) even in less than perfect weather.

Comment: +1 Also, a sailplane has fixed wings that are designed to perform well on average, including somewhat adverse conditions should they occur. A creature evolved to fly and stay airborne has a brain that is probably evolved to tackle a wide range of conditions by adjusting its body in endless many ways, so the max capacity in ideal conditions may even be greater in comparison.

Comment: Just to note. In your sailplane analogy the sailplane itself equates only to the wings of Q. northropi i.e. the plane is solely responsible for providing lift. The body of the animal proper in contrast contains all the mass necessary to initiate and sustain flight in the first place. This means they can't really be separated in the way you describe. In reality the payload would be what the animal could carry on top of its own weight. Same way as the payload of an aircraft is its max load weight not it's total (empty) weight minus the wing weight.  So pay load would be considerably reduced.

Comment: @Mon: The *entire* standard sailplane weighs 200 kg. The wings themselves are very very much lighter. And sailplanes [can sustain flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(soaring)) for many hours, by exploiting ascending air currents -- the practical limitation has more to do with the pilot becoming tired and needing to sleep and take care of other natural businesses. You do have a point about *initiating* flight; sailplanes can take off by themselves without external help only in very favorable and rather rare conditions.

Answer (score 7):

Large birds can carry [up to their own weight](https://a-z-animals.com/blog/the-10-strongest-birds-on-earth-and-how-much-they-can-lift/) **very briefly**. This is generally a momentum-driven pick up and throw action, to kill or stun the prey for consumption. Continuous carry reaches up to half the body weight, but seriously restricting the bird's flight envelope.

It's not certain if the Quetzalcoatlus could fly at all. If it could, its continuous carrying margins were probably smaller in relative terms than for more efficiently-sized birds. Its dynamic lift capability, however, was probably very good, due to very high speeds possible and required at such weight.

In short, it was most likely able to carry about 1/3 its mass continuously, and probably able to lift-and-throw close to its body weight. Which is debated, but modern estimates agree on 100+ kg.

In summary:

- Pick up enemy warriors, even in full armor, and toss them - sure.
- Carry a humanoid - possibly, but you'll have to pick smaller species or just smaller people.

It's not clear if they'd be possible to domesticate to the point of riding, without magical means.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of guesswork in this, because pterosaurs don't fly like anything that comes close to their size so comparison is hard. If we look a the the strongest living fliers like harpy eagles can carry about twice their mass for a short distance. Quetzalcoatlus has a variety of mass estimates and is likely not a strength focused flier, but it should be able to carry an 150lb adult human without that much problem and probably a few hundred pounds for at least a short distance.